# How to create a custom adapter for Lightning Connect using apex connector framework

Tags: lightning-connect

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_external_data_apex_adapter.htm

In this link sample code is given but when I am implementing getting this error
**Error: Compile Error: Invalid class: connectionparams at line 7 column 13**
(because of this variable `private DataSource.ConnectionParams connectionInfo;`

Please help me if some one already created a custom adapter for Lightning connector using apex connector framework.

I am not able to extend DataSource.Connection and DataSource.Provider classe while creating new 2 classes for  custom adapter for Lightning Connect,

Comment: Did `global class DriveDataSourceProvider extends DataSource.Provider` compile without difficulty? It appears to me as though that class needs to be created first as it declares the `DataSource.Connection class` which uses `connectionparams`.

Comment: yes, I just tried with  ` class DriveDataSourceProvider` this also give me some error. `Compile Error: Invalid class: authenticationcapability at line 18 column 14 
`
I think 'DataSource.AuthenticationCapability' is not available in dev org.

Comment: 'DataSource' this namespace is not available at all.
`global class LoopbackDataSourceProvider extends DataSource.Provider {

 }`
in this 2 line of code also error is producable.
`Invalid class: provider`

Comment: Oh, good point, nearly asked in my initial comments whether you had Lightning Connect enabled in your org, along with anything else for the newest features.

Comment: How can enable or check for lightning connect ?
however `External Data Source` is available.

Comment: If you're in a Dev Org, it should be there. Try the [Trailhead Lightning Direct Objects Module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/lightning_connect) to see if it's working. You may need a new Dev Org if it's not. If you have a Production Org, you'll need to ask your Acct Rep for a trial.

Comment: ohoo sf is really bad.
they haven't mentioned nowhere that a lightning org is required for this. I wasted my whole day. it's working in lightning org

Comment: Yes, Direct Objects isn't a freebie. It's in the Docs. It's like a $4k/yr add-on to SF.

Comment: then why it is free in Lightning dev org.
thanks for saving my next day.

Comment: So people can develop for it (App Exchange, etc) and/or learn how to use its features.

Comment: Ankuli, did you ever resolve this issue? Can you post your code?